# Collecting emails

Tags: basic4android

Below is (the main bit) of my code to collect emails and save them in a text file.
But my text file isn't happening. Something wrong in my Sub Email_valid routine
Any clues ?

Thanks in advance, Steve

Sub txtemail_EnterPressed

```
    Dim matcher1 As Matcher

Goodemail=False

matcher1 = Regex.Matcher("\w+@\w+\.\w+", txtemail)

    Do While Matcher1.Find
        Goodemail=True
    Loop 
    If Goodemail=False Then
        Msgbox("please input a valid email address", "Sorry")
    Else
        Msgbox("You will recieve an email shortly","Thank you")
        Email_valid
    End If
```

End Sub

Sub Email_valid

```
Writer.Initialize(File.OpenOutput(File.DirDefaultExternal, "Emai1s.txt",True))
Writer.WriteLine(txtemail)
Writer.Close 
txtemail.Text=""
Goodemail=False
```

End Sub

Comment: OK, for some reason I've got a -1. I'm trying to write a txt file to the sd card (which is present), but the file just doesn't get made, as a very very newbie have I misunderstood somethiing ??

Comment: Hi Guys, OK It is getting made (found it now), but the file contains left, top, width, height, tag AND the email text. I only want it to save email txt (so it can be read into a PC using a 3rd party piece of software), why is the additional stuff there ? can it be ommitted easily ?

Comment: I found the file - DOH ! However - to only get the text to write it was

Writer.WriteLine(txtemail.text) - missing off the .text wrote other txtemail properties.

The delights of being a newbie I guess.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote:

```
Writer.WriteLine(txtemail)
```

Writes the string representation of EditText to the file.